# Ajax get multiple values from a link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link that I would like to get multiple values from to submit through Ajax. So how would I select the streamitem_creator/target/content and type_id from this link to pass into share.php?

```
echo"<a title='Share ".$poster_name['fullusersname']."s status' href='include/share.php?streamitem_creator=".$streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']."&streamitem_target=".$_SESSION['id']."&streamitem_content=".$streamitem_data['streamitem_content']."&streamitem_type_id=4'/>Share</a>";
```

I've come up with my soloution user data- within the link

LINK

```
 echo'<a class="sharelink" title="Share '.$poster_name['fullusersname'].'s status" href="#"
     data-streamitem_creator='.$streamitem_data['streamitem_creator'].'
     data-streamitem_target='.$_SESSION['id'].'
     data-streamitem_content='.$streamitem_data['streamitem_content'].'
     data-streamitem_type_id=4>Share</a>';
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sharelink').click(function(e){

var streamitem_creator = $(this).data('streamitem_creator');
var streamitem_target = $(this).data('streamitem_target');
var streamitem_content = $(this).data('streamitem_content');
var streamitem_type_id = $(this).data('streamitem_type_id');

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "../include/share.php",
data: { streamitem_creator: streamitem_creator, streamitem_target: streamitem_target, streamitem_content: streamitem_content, streamitem_type_id: streamitem_type_id }, 
success: function(msg){
$('#result').html(msg);
e.preventDefault(); 
}
});
});
});
```

Comment: the question is little unclear though

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Share Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052231/custom-share-button)

Comment: It looks like your link contains plenty of data - is your issue submitting it via AJAX?

Comment: I've read around and come up with the solution. I've added it to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `<a>` elements href attribute you could do:

```
var link = $('a[href^="include/share.php?streamitem_creator"]').attr('href');
```

but using an ID would be more specific and simpler.

To get an array of the querystring values you could do :

```
var qs = link.split('?')[1].split('&');
```

but it's hard to tell what the querystring looks like when it's all in PHP ?